# How to get fields from a kendo grid inside of another grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid with another grid in the detail template in my .net mvc application. The sub grid has the fields Id, Name, Total, and Score. I would like to be able to define a column like this

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"myFunction(#=Id#)\">LinkText</a>");
```

The interesting part being the `myFunction(#=Id#)`, when I do this I get an error saying Id is undefined. It works with the main grid but not the subgrid, Is there any way to access the fields of the subgrid? Thanks.

Here is my view:

```
@( Html.Kendo().Grid<WinStream.WebUI.Models.ServiceItemGridModel>()
    .Name("ManageSIGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(
            "#=showSIFlag(Flagged)#" +
            "#=showSILock(Locked)#" +
            "#=showSIDeactive(Activated)#"
        ).Width(75);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(160);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Customer).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Location).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(o => o.City);
        columns.Bound(o => o.State).Width(60);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Type);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Style);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Material);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadServiceItems", "Bids", new { bidId = Model.BidID }))
        .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
    )
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable(f => f
        .Extra(false)
    )
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("biditemgrid")
    .Navigatable()
    .Pageable(page => page.Refresh(true).PageSizes(true))
    .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Virtual(true).Height(300))
    .Selectable(select => select.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .AutoBind(true)
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
```

)

```
<script id="biditemgrid" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @( Html.Kendo().Grid<WinStream.WebUI.Models.BidItemGridModel>()
            .Name("BidItemGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(50);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(160);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Total).Width(75).Title("Total Price");
                columns.Bound(o => o.Score).Width(75);
            .Sortable()
            .Filterable(f => f
                .Extra(false)
            )
            .Navigatable()
            .Pageable()
            .Selectable(select => select.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template(
                "<p class=\"float-left big-text no-margin-bottom\">Vendors</p>" 
            ))
            .DataSource(data => data
                .Ajax()
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .PageSize(5)
                .Read(read => read.Action("ReadBidItems", "Bids", new { bidId = Model.BidID, siId = "#=Id#" }))
                .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
            )
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the sharp symbols with slashes. Currently it is evaluated by the outer Grid and since there is no such field for the master Grid it throws this error.

```
myFunction(\\#=Id\\#)
```